Calculate the Basis B and C
Let
$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 3 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -3 & -2
\end{array}\right]
$
and $ f: \mathbb{R}^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} $ the linear map given by $ f(x)=A x $. Determine a base $ B $ of $ \mathbb{R}^{4} $ and a base $C $ of $ \mathbb{R}^{3} $, so that the matrix of $ f $ the shape
$
\Phi _{C}^{B}(f)=\left[\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$
i have calculated the kernal of A and got
$
  B = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 11 \\ -8 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 9 \\ -7 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}
  $
but i do not know how to continue after that

You are almost done! Now, $C=(u,v,w)$ where $v=f(e_2)$ and $u+v=f(e_1)$, where $e_1,e_2$ are the two first vectors of $B$.

@AnneBauval so v is the 2nd column of A , and u is 1st column of A - v, and what's w ? also why is u = 1st column of A - v ?

$w$ is any vector such that $(u,v,w)$ is linearly independent. And if $e_1$ is the first vector of $B$ and $u,v$ are the two first vectors of $C$, then $f(e_1)=u+v$ by definition of the first column of $\Phi _C^B(f)$.

@AnneBauval ok , thanks this indeed works :)

@AnneBauval but is there somewhere i can see more of this examples , like what if have have only $e_1$ instead for $e_1$ and $e_2$ ? i would like to see how is the case for other examples like if i got instead of $e_1$, $e_4$ or $e_3$ what do i do and so on

I don't understand what you mean by "if I have only $e_1$ instead for $e_1$ and $e_2$". For other examples, you can replace at will the two matrices $A$ and $\Phi _{C}^{B}(f)$ of this exercise by two equivalent matrices, i.e. two  $m\times n$  matrices with the same rank, and train to find some convenient basis $B$ of $\Bbb R^n$ and $C$ of $\Bbb R^m$.
